# Cant resolve PATH issue in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, java-8

Hi i'm trying to build an app in Cordova yet i have hit a road block. Can someone please help me with pointing everything to the right PATH.

I run the following commands no problem.

```
cordova create studioproject online.cbradio studioproject
cordova platforms/add android
cordova platform add android
cordova prepare android
```

Then i run into problems....

```
john@john-Inspiron-3531:~/cordova/studioproject$ cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/john/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/john/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.3
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

OK so I have installed the SDK

```
john@john-Inspiron-3531:~/cordova/studioproject$ cd /home/john/Android/Sdk
john@john-Inspiron-3531:~/Android/Sdk$ ls
build-tools  fonts     patcher   platforms       skins          tools
emulator     licenses  platform  platform-tools  system-images
john@john-Inspiron-3531:~/Android/Sdk$ echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT 
/home/john/Android/Sdk
```

The output of installed jdk

```
john@john-Inspiron-3531:~/Android/Sdk$ sudo update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I seem to have met the requirements. And also...

```
john@john-Inspiron-3531:~/Android/Sdk$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I am sure everything is in place yet i am getting nowhere. What am i missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following to ~/.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```